# Forever running SELECT query

Tags: sql, session, oracle10g

How can I make a sql `SELECT` query run forever in oracle 10g? It should go to completion and should be running forever until stopped by killing the session.

Comment: Could you tell us what you wish to accomplish by that?

Comment: I have to write code for stopping any non-production DBs from front end(say using JSP). So I want a query that is non-productive utilizing CPU doing nothing.

Comment: 0_0 This strikes me as a horrible, **horrible** idea.  Either put that validation into the front end or--if you must--set up a daemon that monitors database connections to your application.

Comment: http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2011/04/16/infinite-query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dummy
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY level > 0
```

If you want it to “fork” a bit more:

```
WITH x AS ( SELECT column_value y FROM TABLE(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('a','b','c','d','e','f'))
          )
SELECT y FROM x CONNECT BY level > 0;
```